# jQuery: if child has class, add class/css to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, parent-child, addclass

I would like to add hover function to (a) if it's child (img) has class .ls-thumb-active ... Here is an example of the html

```
<a href="#" class="ls-thumb-1" style="width: 400px; height: 125px;">
    <img src="http://ldngrp.co/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/apprenticeships.jpg" class style="opacity: 0.7"></a>

<a href="#" class="ls-thumb-2" style="width: 400px; height: 125px;">
   <img src="http://ldngrp.co/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/apprenticeships.jpg" class="ls-thumb-active" style="opacity: 1"></a>
```

This is a wordpress plugin, and already has a hover event (opacity 0.7>1), however I would like to also add the css styles to the parent (a) when the child (img) has class .ls-thumb-active... I have applied these styles to .shadow in css...

```
box-shadow: 0 0 40px 1px rgba(17,17,17,0.2);
z-index: 2;
```

I have come up with a few lines of jQuery, but I have no idea why it is not working! Here is what I have tried so far...

```
$('a.ls-thumb-1:has(img.ls-thumb-active)').addClass('shadow');
$('.ls-thumb-active').parent().addClass('shadow');
$( "a:has(img.ls-thumb-active)" ).addClass( "shadow" );
$('a:has(.ls-thumb-active)').addClass('shadow');
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you :)

Comment: `$(".ls-thumb-active").parent().addClass("shadow");` works perfectly for me. So does `$('a:has(img.ls-thumb-active)').addClass('shadow');`

Comment: So really you want to add hover function to all `a` elements.  and toggle the class depending if it's image active or not?

Comment: Yes, but only toggle when the child element has class .ls-thumb-active!

Answer (score 0):

You're close...
You just need to select it differently
`$('a .ls-thumb-active').addClass('shadow');`

That should work as long as that DOM element is available on page load.

EDIT (Per OP's Original Request):

```
$.fn.addShadowToParent = function() {
    this.parent().addClass('shadow');
};

$('a .ls-thumb-active').addShadowToParent();
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/cameck/pen/ZOOorR)

NOTE: 
On WordPress you usually have to use `jQuery` instead of `$` to get it working.

Comment: OP wants to add the `shadow` class to the `<a>` tag. This selects, and then adds the class to the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Give me 1 sec and I'll fix it before more down votes come

Comment: Your first suggestion -
$('a .ls-thumb-active').addClass('shadow');
works in a js fiddle, but not my site!

Comment: Try using `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: using jQuery instead doesn't work... I'm wondering if it's because of what you said about the DOM element being available on page load as it seems to work everywhere else, sorry I'm such a newbie with js! Do you know how I could get around this at all?

Comment: Wrap your code in this: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {}`

Comment: Is the image there when you load the page? Are there any errors being output in the JS console?

Comment: Yes the image is there when I load the page... It seems that it must be interrupting some js elsewhere on the site, I have 3 errors on the Form Assembly plugin...

- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

- (index):278 Uncaught ReferenceError: wFORMS is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):278

- localization-en_US.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: wFORMS is not defined(anonymous function) @ localization-en_US.js:4

Comment: this is when I wrap the code in -  jQuery(document).ready(function() {}

Comment: Oh, I think I get it... You're displaying this in an `iframe` aren't you?

Comment: No it's not in an iframe, although the forms that it seems to be interrupting are in iframes!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114858/discussion-between-cameck-and-user3541921).