# How can I override a parent class on one element only using CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, overriding, parent-child

I am trying to override the padding set in 'class=image' (set in a parent div) however target this override using a class set in the 7th child of that parent div using CSS only. Can I do this by changing the parent class for it to target only that 7th nested Childs class?

```
<div class="image hero header">
    <div class="umb">
     <div class="grid">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="hero-2020">
          <div class="override 2020-image post">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Here's the CSS for all 6 previous classes:

```
<style>
  .image{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 1.5em 0 6em 0;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   position: relative;
   background-position-x: 50%;}

  .override{
   padding: 0px !important;}
  
  .image.umb{
  margin: auto;
  top: 1em;
  height: 50%;
  width: 1005;}

  div .grid{
  display: block;}

  .container{
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;}

  .clearfix{
  margin: 0px;
  zoom: 1;}

  .col-sm-12{
  width: 100%;}

 .hero-2020{
 padding-left: 0px !important;
 padding-right: 0px !important;}

</style>
```

I have tried to use the CSS nth child concept without much luck. So I'm hoping I can use something a little more specific when writing out the element in CSS, for example > override.image{styles} ? Thanks.

Comment: you are using nth child wrong - nth child is for the nth direct child of the parent not nested child also css only flows down so you cannot affect the parent class based on it's child

Comment: Thanks Pete, it was a bit of a long shot however I can't access the HTML or JS. Using a nested child class to override the parent class is what I'm looking to do yes

Comment: yeah can't be done then

Comment: ok doke. Is there a way I can change the 'parent' class to only target that 'image' class? for example>  .parent.image{} ?

Comment: put a space in between the first class and the second class - `.parent .image {}` - with the space it means `.image` is inside `.parent`.  without the space, it means an element with both image and parent classes

Comment: Thanks @Pete , this doesn't seem to work for some bizarre reason, maybe I'm doing something wrong my end. Maybe because there are a few more classes being set in the same element (please see above), so will I have to specify .image.hero.header .override.2020.post ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this if you want all children with *.override* class having padding 0:

```
div.image div.override{padding: 0}
```

Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

In particular:

> .class1 .class2   .name1 .name2   Selects all elements with name2 that is
> a descendant of an element with name1

I suggest to use *!important* only when is strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks kiafiore, this doesn't seem to work but will take a look at the link :)

Comment: @gilesj Sorry I've read only now that you want to change parent from child... Unfortunately you can't :(

Comment: My bad @kiafiore I just need to change the class used in the parent to only affect that child one..

Comment: So you need to change only the padding on the 7th child div or the parent one? Sorry but today I'm a little bit out of the world :D Can you also share all the styles of the other css classes? So we can better help you

Comment: yes only on the 7th child div, however the .image class is affecting it. Thanks, I've just updated the styles..

Comment: @gilesj Thanks. And what about the other 5 parent divs? Do they have css classes?

Comment: yes, I've added them just now, please see above :) thanks.

Comment: Sorry but, can you also modify the code snippet with the html tags? In this way we can see the correct stylization of all the divs. Ty

Comment: no problem, HTML's all updated, hope this helps?

Comment: just as an FYI, it's the padding (1.5em 0 6em 0) in .image I'm trying to override. I could easily target that .image class and put it at the end of the stylesheet however I want it to affect not all .image classes but the ones which have a nested child (in this case the 'override' class) ? thanks

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I'm afraid but I think the only way to do what you want is using javascript. Watch this, pheraps can help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861853/jquery-if-child-has-class-add-class-css-to-parent)

Comment: ah what a shame! Thanks for your help :D